# Can chameleon support block caching?

Tags: python, caching, pyramid, chameleon

I'm evaluating chameleon as a template renderer for Pyramid. 
Some feature quite useful from Django, which also works with mako, is [caching](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/caching.html).

I couldn't find a similar feature by looking at the documentation, neither with a quick google search.

Is there a similar feature with Chameleon ?  If not, how can one deal with potentially long template rendering ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in support for caching the rendered result of a Chameleon template.

There seems to be support for Beaker together with Pyramid. The thread below discusses that implementation.

http://groups.google.com/group/pylons-devel/browse_thread/thread/efe8fd52e6643c47/2675c7098bb32413